# Ruby on rails tutorial by Michael Hartl Ch 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Hi im completing [this of ruby](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) on rails.

I just wanted to get it over with so i stayed up a little to finish it off.
lo and behold coding while tired I have made a stupid mistake somewhere and now i cant find it. its probably something simple but i just cant see it.

I made the error somewhere after the section [11.2.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax)

When i run bundle exec rspec spec/ I get the following error

```
  1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controlle
r visiting the following page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Sign in') }
       expected #has_title?("Sign in") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (6 levels) in <
top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controlle
r visiting the followers page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Sign in') }
       expected #has_title?("Sign in") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (6 levels) in <
top (required)>'

Finished in 16.24 seconds
142 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:55 # Authentication authoriza
tion for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the following page

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:60 # Authentication authoriza
tion for non-signed-in users in the Users controller visiting the followers page
```

Here is my authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
   require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end
  describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end
  end
  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end
         describe "visiting the following page" do
          before { visit following_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the followers page" do
          before { visit followers_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end
    end


    describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
       before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
       end

       describe "after signing in" do
          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
          end
        end
  end



    describe "in the Microposts controller" do

        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post microposts_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
    end

    describe "in the Relationships controller" do
        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post relationships_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end

    describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete relationship_path(1) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end
    end
  end


  describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
      describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
end
end
```

I think its a problem with this file but if you want to see my other files just comment and ill post the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add :following and :followers to the before_action in your UsersController ?

```
before_action :signed_in_user,
            only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
```

Comment: nice you're pretty fast. Thx!